# Qual versão do Visual Studio usar?

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio-2017, ide, aplicação-desktop

Olá, estou com um problema relacionado a qual versão do Visual Studio utilizar. 
O cenário é o seguinte, a empresa em que eu trabalho não tem nada a ver com desenvolvimento de software, porém eu sou programador e decidimos usar essa habilidade para desenvolver um sistema (desktop) para auxiliar em vários processos do setor, sendo que isso pode se expandir.
Minha experiência em programação é toda em C# e Java, e para a finalidade do sistema, com certeza C# é a melhor opção, portanto decidi usar o VS (Visual Studio) como IDE para esse projeto.
A empresa é grande, porém eu sou o único (pelo menos em meu setor) que vou desenvolver o sistema (pois é algo interno do setor), e esse sistema vai ser expandido para mais um setor da empresa (apenas na implementação) que tem relação com o setor que atuo.

Eis a questão, qual VS devo usar ? Community, Professional ou Enterprise ?

Comment: Acredito que inicialmente o Community já atenda suas necessidades.

Comment: Depende da necessidade. Se vc não vai precisar de nada além do básico, por exemplo, pq não usar uma versão básica gratuita?

Comment: O que seria além do básico ? Jean